# How do applications know how return the data an API requested?

Tags: json, python-3.x, api

Let's say I created Twilio. Below is their alerts API

https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/monitor-alert:

Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client
```

Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure

```
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

alert = client.monitor.alerts('NOXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').fetch()

print(alert.alert_text)
```

Example JSON API response:

```
{
  "account_sid": "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "alert_text": "alert_text",
  "api_version": "2010-04-01",
  "date_created": "2015-07-30T20:00:00Z",
  "date_generated": "2015-07-30T20:00:00Z",
  "date_updated": "2015-07-30T20:00:00Z",
  "error_code": "error_code",
  "log_level": "log_level",
  "more_info": "more_info",
  "request_method": "GET",
  "request_url": "http://www.example.com",
  "request_variables": "request_variables",
  "resource_sid": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
  "response_body": "response_body",
  "response_headers": "response_headers",
  "request_headers": "request_headers",
  "sid": "NOXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "url": "https://monitor.twilio.com/v1/Alerts/NOXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "service_sid": "PNe2cd757cd5257b0217a447933a0290d2"
}
```

How does the application return the data above? How does it know to return the above data?

DO you have to create an object with the data above to respond to said API call> Does the programmer need to write a special function, they would not normally create if they didn't want to provide API access to the application, to respond to the api call that will return the data?

So for example if I had a website that enabled people to enter in their first and last names into a database. I would then need to write a program that utilized some function that inserted the names. If I then wanted to create an API to give others to retrieve the names from the database I would need to create another function, that I wouldn't create if I didn't have the API, to retrieve the names for the API call. Or I would create an API call that would make a request to some function that would return an object with all the data I said my API call would return; or the function would go searching around for the data create an object and then return the information to the person who made the call.

Comment: An application doesn't know anything.    The developer of the application reads the specification of the API (or particular function used) and works out how to write code so the application provides required data.

Comment: If I had calculator.com with an external API that enabled Twilio users to add. An external API call was made to add and at the same time on the website a user added. How does calculator.com know to return the correct output to the external API that enabled Twilio users to add and calculator.com users to do the same. When Twilio users and calc.com users are using the same add function, with the same parameters, and at the exact same time how does calculator.com know ?

Comment: If I had calculator.com with an external API that enabled Twilio users to add. A Twilio user made an API call to add and at the same time on calculator.com a user added. How does calculator.com know to return the correct output to each user when Twilio users and calc.com users are using the same add function, with the same parameters, and at the exact same time?

Comment: You need to work to understand what an "interface"  (the 'I' in API) actually is.   You are demonstrating that you do not understand it.

Comment: You can return anything you want. It can be a 1:1 representation of a database row. It can be static text. It can be a static file on a disk. It can be randomized data. You might use objects, you might not have any objects at all. Try writing a hello world webserver first. Then make it return a JSON of something. Then return something from a database. Small steps. Pretend that Twilio doesn't exist for a few days.

Comment: Let's say I had a web app that exclusively and only finds max in an array.

    int findMax(int[] array, int length) {
        int max = array[0];
        int i;
    
        for(i=1;i++;i<length){
            max = programmer1Max(max, array[i]);
        }
    
        return max;
     }

If I wanted to create an API call that found max it would pass in the function variables to find max. Now if I wanted to have a new API call return the timestamp of when a max was found I would have to write new code to be able to respond to this function to find the timestamp for example.

Answer (score 0):

Someone wrote it.  Or maybe they wrote code that wrote it.

But probably someone just wrote it in at least one iteration; but as everything is translated, compiled and interpreted nowadays, what is the difference.

Some of the best external API-services evolved out of internal APIs; like AWS.

The hard part is not throwing together an API, it is testing it, ensuring it is robust and secure and privacy capable sufficiently powerful.